# Ignore <br> in string match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

```
[This regex tester evaluates JavaScript regular expressions]
```

when i match it by this `\[(.*?)]`, it match but when i click enter like this :

```
[This regex tester 
evaluates JavaScript regular expressions]
```

the match not work , how to ignore `<br>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should suffice.

```
\[([^\]]*)\]
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/jK8cD2)

**Note:** If you have multiple strings like the following in a multi-line string, you could also use the following:

```
\[([\S\s]*)\]
```

Or add the non-greedy `?` making it match the least amount possible.

```
\[([\S\s]*?)\]
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/qC9xZ7)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `<tr>` in the line, it is just a new line in between which `.*` will not match.

Try this regex to match:

```
\[([\s\S]*)\]
```

`[\s\S]` will match new lines as well since Javascript doesn't have DOTALL (s) flag.